# Searching on a list of maps does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

It seems like my searching logic is not working. Mr.ChatGPT doesn't even know how to fix it.

```
import 'package:domingo_etr/helpers/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:domingo_etr/models/Goat.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool isSearchVisible = false;
  late FocusNode _searchFocusNode;
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _searchFocusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchFocusNode.removeListener(_onFocusChange);
    _searchFocusNode.dispose();
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onFocusChange() {
    if (!_searchFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      print("TextField value: ${_searchController.text}");
      setState(() {
        isSearchVisible = false;
      });
      _searchController.clear();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.white,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
    );

    List<Goat> goats = [];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          "Apacapra",
          style: GoogleFonts.satisfy(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          isSearchVisible
              ? Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _searchController,
                      focusNode: _searchFocusNode,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search by name",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        suffix: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _searchFocusNode.unfocus();
                          },
                          child: FaIcon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.xmark,
                            size: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // Update the existing list based on the entered text
                          goats = goats
                              .where((goat) =>
                                  goat.pasternId
                                      .toLowerCase()
                                      .contains(value.toLowerCase()) ||
                                  goat.breed
                                      .toLowerCase()
                                      .contains(value.toLowerCase()) ||
                                  goat.name
                                      .toLowerCase()
                                      .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                              .toList();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isSearchVisible = true;
                    });
                    _searchFocusNode.requestFocus();
                  },
                  icon: FaIcon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.magnifyingGlass,
                    size: 20,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: DbHelper.getAllGoats(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    // While the Future is still running, display a loading indicator
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    // Handle errors
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    // Handle the case where snapshot.data is null
                    return Text('No data available');
                  } else {
                    // Data is available, proceed with displaying it
                    goats = snapshot.data!.toList();

                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: goats.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final goat = goats[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text('ID: ${goat.pasternId}'),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            'Breed: ${goat.breed}, Weight: ${goat.currentWeight}, Name: ${goat.name}',
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final goat = Goat(
                  pasternId: "GT-12",
                  name: "Nene",
                  breed: "Anglo-Nubian",
                  dateOfBirth: "2019-02-12",
                  currentWeight: 40,
                );
                DbHelper.insertGoat(goat);
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("Add"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

db_herlper.dart file

```
import 'package:domingo_etr/models/Goat.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DbHelper {
  // Constants
  static const dbName = 'goat_management.db';
  static const dbVersion = 1;

  // Table constants
  static const tbGoat = 'Goat';
  static const tbVaccine = 'Vaccine';
  static const tbVitamin = 'Vitamin';

  // Columns for the 'Goat' table
  static const colGoatId = 'goatId';
  static const colPasternId = 'pasternId';
  static const colName = 'name';
  static const colBreed = 'breed';
  static const colDateOfBirth = 'dateOfBirth';
  static const colCurrentWeight = 'currentWeight';

  // Columns for the 'Vaccine' table
  static const colVaccineId = 'vaccineId';
  static const colVaccineGoatId = 'goatId'; // Foreign key reference
  static const colVaccineName = 'vaccineName';
  static const colVaccineBrandName = 'brandName';
  static const colVaccineType = 'type';
  static const colVaccineDosage = 'dosage';

  // Columns for the 'Vitamin' table
  static const colVitaminId = 'vitaminId';
  static const colVitaminGoatId = 'goatId'; // Foreign key reference
  static const colVitaminName = 'vitaminName';
  static const colVitaminBrandName = 'brandName';
  static const colVitaminType = 'type';
  static const colVitaminDosage = 'dosage';

  // Methods for db

  static Future<Database> openDB() async {
    var path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), DbHelper.dbName);
    var db = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: DbHelper.dbVersion,
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        _createTables(db);
      },
      onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) {
        _upgradeTables(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
      },
    );
    return db;
  }

  static void _createTables(Database db) {
    // Create the 'Goat' table
    var goatTableSql = '''
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tbGoat(
        $colGoatId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        $colPasternId TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        $colName TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colBreed TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colDateOfBirth TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colCurrentWeight INTEGER NOT NULL
      )
    ''';
    db.execute(goatTableSql);

    // Create the 'Vaccine' table
    var vaccineTableSql = '''
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tbVaccine(
        $colVaccineId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        $colVaccineGoatId INTEGER REFERENCES $tbGoat($colGoatId),
        $colVaccineName TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colVaccineBrandName TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colVaccineType TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colVaccineDosage TEXT NOT NULL
      )
    ''';
    db.execute(vaccineTableSql);

    // Create the 'Vitamin' table
    var vitaminTableSql = '''
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tbVitamin(
        $colVitaminId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        $colVitaminGoatId INTEGER REFERENCES $tbGoat($colGoatId),
        $colVitaminName TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colVitaminBrandName TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colVitaminType TEXT NOT NULL,
        $colVitaminDosage INTEGER NOT NULL
      )
    ''';
    db.execute(vitaminTableSql);
  }

  static void _upgradeTables(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Handle table upgrades here
    if (newVersion <= oldVersion) return;

    // Drop existing tables and recreate them
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tbGoat');
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tbVaccine');
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tbVitamin');

    // Recreate tables
    _createTables(db);
  }

  // Methods na CRUD Ops -----------------

  // Get a goat
  static Future<List<Goat>> getAllGoats() async {
    final Database db = await openDB();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query(tbGoat);

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Goat(
        goatId: maps[i]['goatId'],
        pasternId: maps[i]['pasternId'],
        name: maps[i]['name'],
        breed: maps[i]['breed'],
        dateOfBirth: maps[i]['dateOfBirth'],
        currentWeight: maps[i]['currentWeight'],
      );
    });
  }

  // Insert a goat record
  static Future<void> insertGoat(Goat goat) async {
    final Database db = await openDB();

    await db.insert(
      tbGoat,
      goat.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }
}
```

I'm expecting it to display the result of the filtered list, but it's not working. Please bear with me, I'm just a beginner at programming. Ps. I intentionally hard-coded the insertion of a record when clicking the Add button

Comment: What is `DbHelper`? It is not defined anywhere in the code, which is kind of ridiculous since you have shown all the code for the views that are irrelevant to the logic, but failed to provide the detail for something that may actually matter

Comment: i updated it. my appologies

Comment: I'm only guessing, but could it be the case where at each update (in the `setState`), you modified the local variable `goat`, but during the build it still looks for the data from `DbHelper.getAllGoats()`?

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

As [@MMZK1526 brilliantly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77713847/searching-on-a-list-of-maps-does-not-work#comment137007452_77713847), the error is that inside your `FutureBuilder`, you're still fetching the original `getAllGoats` data. This is the workflow:

1. The `build` method is called for the first time. Since the `goats` variable
   is *inside* the `build` method, it's initialized to `[]`. The `FutureBuilder` fetches `getAllGoats` and it sets the local `goats` variable to `snapshot.data!.toList()`.
2. You type something in the `TextField`. You do a `setState` updating the local `goats` variable with all the filters applied.
3. Since you did a `setState`, the `build` method is called for the second time. Go to the step 1 and see that it'll reset the `goats` variable and fetch `getAllGoats` again, replacing your filter.

### The solution

You can make two lists: one which will contain all the goats and another that you contain only the displayed goats.

This is a minified copy of your code that you can adapt:

```
class _State extends State<Screen> {
  // Make `goats` not a local variable, but a field of `_State`
  List<Goat>? _goats;
  // Also make a variable to show only the displayed goats
  List<Goat>? _displayedGoats;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Read from the database helper *once* and update the screen
    DbHelper.getAllGoats().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _goats = _displayedGoats = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Goat>? goats = _displayedGoats;
    if (goats == null) {
      return Text('Loading goats...');
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        // The text field used to filter by text
        TextField(
          onChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              _displayedGoats = _goats!.where((goat) => goat.name.contains(text)).toList();
            });
          },
        ),
        // If you want, a button to display all goats without any filter
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _displayedGoats = _goats!.toList();
            });
          },
        ),
        // A list to display the goats
        ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => Text(goats[i].name),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you should put the

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.white,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
);
```

inside the `initState` too.